# What are the essential uses of built-in Skolem functions in model theory?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Built-in Skolem functions are often used to present classical results in model theory in textbooks.  However, I noticed that the use of built-in Skolem function can often be avoided.  The following are some examples:

1. Loewenheim-Skolem theorems.  Having names for the Skolem functions is useful but not necessary; one just has to be careful in adding points to your model.
2. Quantifier elimination.  The so-called Morleyization, i.e., naming  each definable subsets by a new relation symbol, suffices.
3. Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski models.  There seems to be a way around since in continuous logic the existence of indiscernibles is proved without built-in Skolem functions, I'm told.  (This is actually the motivation for this question.)

Hence, my question is: what are the essential uses of built-in Skolem functions in model theory?

Comment: How do you prove downward Lowenheim-Skolem without Skolem functions? Being careful about how we add points sounds like using Skolem functions but not calling them that (the way we add points amounts to a collection of Skolem functions).

Comment: @NoahSchweber My point is that you *use* Skolem functions, but they need not be named by function symbols in the structure.

Comment: The existence of definable Skolem functions in models of some set theory plus a "canonicity" axiom like [$V=L$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility) is frequently important in set theory (see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597)); is this an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was looking for an example involving more "ordinary" structure, but I didn't specify that in my post.  Thank you for your example.

Comment: For the existence of indiscernibles we do not need Skolem functions. This is mainly using Ramsey's theorem (and a whole lot of compactness of course, as always). Maybe you confused that bit with Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski models, where such an indiscernible sequence is used in the construction.

Comment: @MarkKamsma  You're right.  Do you know how they use indiscernibles in continuous logic?  Do they have counterparts of EM models?

Comment: @Pteromys In the same way we use them in is first-order logic. There isn't really that much difference: you have essentially the same tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that you can almost always get around the Skolem function issue in continuous logic, either by using a different method or by literally discretizing the structure in question (see the discussion in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.10673) for instance), there is one thing you can prove with Skolem functions in discrete logic that I do not know how to generalize to continuous logic (which I originally discussed in [an answer to a MathOverflow question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144104/is-there-a-notion-of-skolemization-for-continuous-logic/388991#388991)):

> Is it true that every complete continuous theory $T$ can be extended by definable predicates and functions to a theory $T'$ that is axiomatized by universal sentences?

As I mention in my other answer, however, I believe this question is equivalent to asking whether every continuous theory can be Skolemized in the traditional sense (i.e., expanded by definable functions in such a way that every substructure is an elementary substructure), so this may be a slightly circular answer.